# Set Excel 2010 save location to most recently used ("saved to") folder

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'd like to save related excel 2010 documents to the most recently used folder. Is this possible? Excel 2010 defaults to a libraries folder, and extra searching is required to save to the desired (most recently used) folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default file location in the Excel options, but that is not a dynamic address.

As long as the Excel session is open, the Save or Save as command will default to the most recently used folder.

If you are using Windows 7 as your operating system, you can click the "Recent Places" link in the favourites section to find the most recently used folders.